# Оптимизировать запрос, убрать not in

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tasks` WHERE `id` NOT IN(SELECT `tid` FROM `hide`);
```

Ужасно тормозит запрос этот. Записей всего 500-600, а он тормозит. И все это из-за not in, убеждался неоднократно. Как можно сделать иначе?

Comment: про left join что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Я думаю, вам пригодится http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1267. Для повышения квалификации.

Comment: Join'ы тоже не лучше, уже были.

Comment: >И все это из-за not in

________________________

>Join'ы тоже не лучше, уже были

сами себе противоречите. Однако если join не лучше, то проблема скорее всего в вашей базе. Наверняка вытаскиваете что-нибудь огромное. Тут без понимания структуры и содержимого вашей сложно сказать что-то определенное

Comment: @DreamChild, в tasks 2 поля: id(int 10) и title(varchar 10), в hide 3: id(int 10), tid(int 10), uid(int 10) соответственно ничего тяжелого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй это

```
SELECT t.id FROM tasks AS t 
LEFT JOIN h.tid AS h 
ON  t.id = h.tid
WHERE h.tid IS NUL;
```

Comment: Join'ы тоже не лучше, уже были.